# F# type matching with ":? Type as name": why do we need a new name?

Tags: .net, f#, pattern-matching

I was looking at the pattern matching syntax for types in F# described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd547125.aspx#sectionToggle14

Example from that page (slightly modified):

```
open System.Windows.Forms

let RegisterControl (control: Control) =
    match control with
    | :? Button as button -> button.Text <- "Registered."
    | :? CheckBox as checkbox -> checkbox.Checked <- false
    | _ -> ()
```

What I don't understand is why we need to introduce a new name ("button", "checkbox") along with the typecheck. If the match succeeded, the compiler should know that "control" has the desired type and could treat it accordingly in the following expression/statement. In other words, why can't I do this:

```
open System.Windows.Forms

let RegisterControl (control: Control) =
    match control with
    | :? Button -> control.Text <- "Registered."
    | :? CheckBox -> control.Checked <- false
    | _ -> ()
```

This would be similar to the ["type guard" feature in TypeScript 1.4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2014/11/18/what-s-new-in-the-typescript-type-system.aspx).

Is there a good reason why F# doesn't do that [yet]? (Note: I'm running VS 2012.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One obvious reason why you need a new name is when the parameter of `match` is an expression:

```
match some.Method() with
| :? Button -> // What to do here??
```

Of course, the language could support of the notations. In that case, there is no technical reason why you could not do this, but I think there is a pretty good logical reason for not doing this.

Every value in F# has a location where it is explicitly declared (when you're using a value, you can always go to definition). The values that would be defined using this simplified `:? Type` syntax would not really have any declaration

- You could say that they are declared at the point where the original variable is declared, but that's wrong - because there, it would have different type.
- Or you could say that they are declared in some "hidden way", but that would introduce a completely new concept to the language.

That said, I can see why the syntax is nice and useful. But it does not seem to fit well with the logic of how variables work in F#.

Comment: Indeed, that is very obvious. Guess I was too focused on examples. Thank you.

Comment: Example-Driven Language Design :-)

Comment: Example-Driven Language Understanding, with inevitably silly questions :) I won't dare go into language design based solely on examples, promise.

Comment: @MoritzBeutel That comment was not directed at you, but at the TypeScript team! :-)

Answer (score 2):

This would be trading a consistent model for an inconsistent one.

It's not entirely true that you need to introduce a new name. This works quite well:

```
match control with
| :? Button -> doButtonyStuff control
| :? CheckBox -> doCheckBoxyStuff control
| _ -> ()
```

Except of course your `control` value stays a `Control` in the match case bodies. You only introduce the name when you want to do a typecheck (C#-style `is`) and a cast (C#-style `as`) in your match pattern.

What you suggest could easily be imagined as having an implicit shadowing of `control: Control` you use in the match with another `control: Button` after the cast. One problem I see with it is that it has a collateral effect of making the `control: Control` inaccessible in the match case bodies. That might not be a big deal in your particular example, but if you're checking against interface types, it might become unwieldy.

No pattern matching constructs do such an implicit thing today. Unless you do so yourself, your bindings don't get shadowed. That's good if you ask me. Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: I think the situation with interface isn't a problem because .NET generics have similar semantics: you can constrain a type argument to be both an arbitrary type and to implement number of interfaces, and the compiler will treat variables of the type as being either the type or one of the interface, depending on the requested usage.

Comment: It's certainly more of a problem than Button vs Control example. In F# interfaces are only implemented explicitly, so to access interface methods you need to cast to the interface type (at which point you no longer can access non-interface methods, you'd need to cast back to the concrete type). Button probably reexposes everything important that Control provides, so that would be less pain.